# ssis transaction support with ms access

Tags: ms-access, ssis, transactions

Is it basically possible to do transactions with `ssis` and ms access 97! I have tried setting up a complicated package which doesn't work and then tried some transactions with a simple package which worked no problem with SQL server to check I understood the principles. Now the question is does MS Access support or does `ssis` support transactions with access 97...

Anyone have a definite answer?

Any links or tips much appreciated!

Comment: Anything that is server-side ought to be executable from Access with ODBC and passthroughs or via ADO. Can you give a specific example? All the transaction-controlling logic would need to be server-side, which means you might need to construct some server-side sprocs that control the logic of the process.

Comment: Specifically we are exporting from a backend system a personal list which is to be updated. We delete the old list and insert the new. For some reason I've not been able to understand the developer says its not possible with update!... Naturally we would like the delete to roll back if any other stuff goes wrong...and this is within ssis..